Error when generating Germany Tiles with OpenMapTiles
I'm quiet new to the whole Map topic and I'm slowly understanding each working part. So far, I've cloned the latest openmaptiles repository and went along with the README to generate the map-tiles for Albania and hosting them with tileserver-gl. Everything works fine when doing either the ./quickstart.sh or starting the manual process. No errors.
Knowing that the whole process seems to work, I've been trying to generate the maptiles for Germany. I've downloaded the file according to the readme, Geofabrik as the source of the .pbf. Coming to the import-osm step, I keep getting an error though. The data is being processed for like 30min, then I receive the following error: 
parsing PBF: parsing next block header: unmarshaling header: proto: required filed "type" not set
make: *** [Makefile:431: import-osm] Error 1


I've tried it on different days, with different .pdf versions (different day), trying it on my Macbook Pro (M3 Pro) and on my virtual Ubuntu Server LTS 24.04.
Do you guys have any idea what I'm doing wrong? I can't seem to get it right. All previous steps succeed without failure.
